# How to actually apply a saved RF model and predict in Spark2?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

This is a newbie question because I can't seem to find a simple way.

I am doing Airline dataset with Weather data and predict delay if >15min.

Airline Dataset (2007 and 2008): http://stat-computing.org/dataexpo/2009/the-data.html

Weather:

```
wget ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/by_year/2007.csv.gz -O /tmp/weather_2007.csv.gz
wget ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/by_year/2008.csv.gz -O /tmp/weather_2008.csv.gz
```

My code is from this URL https://github.com/neil90/spark_airline_delays/blob/master/spark_airplane.ipynb but I changed it for Spark 2.3:

```
df_airline_2007 = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("/ACMEAirDB/2007/2007.csv")
df_weather_2007 = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header", "false").load("/ACMEAirDB/weather_2007/weather_2007.csv")
df_airline_2008 = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("/ACMEAirDB/2008/2008.csv")
df_weather_2008 = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header", "false").load("/ACMEAirDB/weather_2008/weather_2008.csv")

df_airline_raw = df_airline_2007.unionAll(df_airline_2008)
df_weather_raw = df_weather_2007.unionAll(df_weather_2008)


#Function to create year,month,day into date for airline to join on to weather
def to_date(year,month,day): 
    dt = "%04d%02d%02d" % (year, month, day)
    return dt

sqlContext.udf.register("to_date", to_date)

#Function to discrentize time in airline
def discretize_tod(val):
    hour = int(val[:2])
    if hour < 8:
        return 0
    if hour < 16:
        return 1
    return 2

sqlContext.udf.register("discretize_tod", discretize_tod)

df_airline_raw.registerTempTable("df_airpline_raw")
df_weather_raw.registerTempTable("df_weather_raw")

#Create Final Airline transformation
df_airline = sqlContext.sql("""SELECT 
                            Year as year, Month as month, DayofMonth as day, DayOfWeek as dow,
                            CarrierDelay as carrier, Origin as origin, Dest as dest, Distance as distance, 
                            discretize_tod(DepTime) as tod, CASE WHEN DepDelay >= 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as delay, 
                            to_date(cast(Year as int), cast(Month as int), cast(DayofMonth as int)) As date 
                            FROM df_airpline_raw
                            WHERE Cancelled = 0 AND Origin = 'ORD'""")

#Create Base Weather Transformation Table
df_weather = sqlContext.sql("""SELECT 
                                _C0 AS station,
                                _C1 As date,
                                _C2 As metric,
                                _C3 As value, 
                                _C4 As t1, 
                                _C5 As t2, 
                                _C6 As t3, 
                                _C7 As time
                                FROM df_weather_raw
                                """)


# df_weather.show(10)    


#Create Tmin and Tmax Weather DF
df_weather.registerTempTable("df_weather")

#Create DFs for Weather Tmin and Tmax Values 
df_weather_tmin = sqlContext.sql("""SELECT 
                                        date, 
                                        value as temp_min 
                                    FROM df_weather 
                                    WHERE station = 'USW00094846' 
                                    AND metric = 'TMIN'""")

df_weather_tmax = sqlContext.sql("""SELECT 
                                        date, 
                                        value as temp_max 
                                    FROM df_weather 
                                    WHERE station = 'USW00094846' 
                                    AND metric = 'TMAX'""")

#Join Airline with Weather Tmin and Tmax Dataframes
df_airline_tmin = df_airline.join(df_weather_tmin, 
                                  df_weather_tmin.date == df_airline.date, 
                                  "inner").drop(df_weather_tmin.date)

df_airline_tmin_and_tmax = df_airline_tmin.join(df_weather_tmax, 
                                                df_weather_tmax.date == df_airline_tmin.date, 
                                                "inner").drop(df_weather_tmax.date)

df_airline_tmin_and_tmax.registerTempTable("df_airline_tmin_and_tmax")
df_all = sqlContext.sql("""SELECT 
                                delay,
                                year,
                                month, 
                                day, 
                                dow, 
                                cast (tod AS int) tod, 
                                distance, 
                                temp_min, 
                                temp_max
                            FROM df_airline_tmin_and_tmax""")

#Cache Dataframe because we split it later on
df_all.cache()

#Linear Regression
#import necessary librarys
from pyspark.mllib.regression import  LabeledPoint
# from pyspark.mllib.tree import DecisionTree, RandomForest
from pyspark.mllib.tree import RandomForest
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import DenseVector


#Create labeledPoint Parser
def parseDF(row):
    values = [row.delay, row.month, row.day, row.dow, row.tod, row.distance, row.temp_min, row.temp_max]
    return LabeledPoint(values[0], DenseVector(values[1:]))

#Convert Dataframes to LabeledPoint for modeling
train_data = df_all.filter("year=2007").rdd.map(parseDF)
test_data = df_all.filter("year=2008").rdd.map(parseDF)


#Train Models

modelRF = RandomForest.trainClassifier(train_data, numClasses=2, categoricalFeaturesInfo={},
                                      numTrees=500, impurity='gini', maxDepth=5)


#Apply CART model on Test Data
predictionsRF = modelRF.predict(test_data.map(lambda x: x.features))
predictionsAndLabelsRFRDD = predictionsRF.zip(test_data.map(lambda lp: lp.label))
predictionsAndLabelsRF = predictionsAndLabelsRFRDD.collect()

import pandas as pd

#Create function

def confusion_matrix(predAndLabel):
    y_actual = pd.Series([x for x, y in predAndLabel], name = 'Actual')
    y_pred = pd.Series([y for x, y in predAndLabel], name = 'Predicted')

    matrix = pd.crosstab(y_actual,y_pred)
    accuracy = float(matrix[0][0] + matrix[1][1])/(matrix[0][0] + matrix[0][1] + matrix[1][0] + matrix[1][1])

    return matrix, accuracy


#RandomForest Confusion Matrix and Model Accuracy
df_confusion_RF, accuracy_RF = confusion_matrix(predictionsAndLabelsRF)

print('RF Confusion Matrix:')
print(df_confusion_RF)
print('\nRF Model Accuracy: {0}'.format(accuracy_RF))
```

I got below as output which is correct:

```
RF Confusion Matrix:
Predicted     0.0    1.0
Actual                  
0.0        237594  93003
1.0          2300   2433
RF Model Accuracy: 0.715793397549
```

So my question is: Now I have the model `predictionsRF`, how do I apply it for, let say, a "real world" one record?

This is my newbie attempt:

```
df_validation = sqlContext.sql("""SELECT 
                                1 delay,
                                2008 year,
                                6 month, 
                                19 day, 
                                4 dow, 
                                1 tod, 
                                925 distance, 
                                111 temp_min, 
                                272 temp_max
                            """)

validation_data = df_validation.rdd.map(parseDF)

df_validation.show(1)

validationsRF = modelRF.predict(validation_data.map(lambda x: x.features))
validationsAndLabelsRFRDD = validationsRF.zip(validation_data.map(lambda lp: lp.label))
validationsAndLabelsRF = validationsAndLabelsRFRDD.collect()

print(validationsRF.collect())
```

**1. Am I correct to use `validationsRF.collect()` as the predicted delay result?**

**2. How do I remove `delay` column from `df_validation` and not getting errors (below)?**

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 284.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 284.0 (TID 4544, ip-172-31-40-184.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 1): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 229, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 224, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 372, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in parseDF
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1561, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(item)
AttributeError: delay
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:421)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.hasNext(SerDeUtil.scala:153)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1988)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:170)
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1769)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1758)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2055)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:939)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:938)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor184.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 229, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 224, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 372, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in parseDF
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1561, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(item)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> . Am I correct to use validationsRF.collect() as the predicted delay result?

Why do it at all?

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors

modelRF.predict(Vectors.dense([2008, 6, 19, 4, 1, 925, 111, 272]))
```

Answer (score 2):

> How do I remove delay column from df_validation and not getting errors (below)?

Don't assume it is there, in your `parseDF` function. Specifically the cause of failure is:

```
values = [row.delay, ...]
```

But honestly, just switch to ML Pipeline.